# which info is the true about cpu cores?

Tags: 18.04, cpuinfo

i have a question about my actual number of cpus on my machine. Different methods give me different results...

`htop` shows 4 cores working

`lscpu | grep CPU\(s\):` shows 4

`cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor` shows 4

`cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "cpu cores" | uniq` shows 2

`sensors | grep Core` shows 2

i'm a bit lost...

EDIT:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'model name'
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7500U CPU @ 2.70GHz
```

Comment: It'd be easier to find out by starting with telling us the type of CPU you have.  You can get that by doing `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'model name'`.  Please add the output of this command to your question as an edit to the question.  Once we know the CPU you have, it's easier to search that CPU model online to get the true answer to such a question.

Comment: People, and programs, confuse cores and CPUs all the time. You have 2 cores with 2 threads per core for a total of 4 CPUs.

Comment: @DougSmythies Understandably confusing. It's still only 1 CPU there though, with 2 cores, having 2 threads each. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with the way CPU's are build today.

You have 1 hardware CPU which contains 2 cores which transmit their data on their own bus. Each core has 2 so called threads which can compute on their own, but share a bus to transmit their data. This is calle multithreading and is fairly common nowadays.

But Linux doesn't show this. Instead each thread is seen as a cpu core. So if you have a six or eight core server e.g. htop would show 12 or 16 single cores.

In your case you have a CPU with 2 cores and 4 threads in total.

Take a look again at your command (without uniq), it should show this information 4 times right?

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "cpu cores"
```

Comment: This is not quite true. "Threads" are not necessarily actual cores. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_multithreading There are 2 cores on the die, each core supporting 2 threads.

Comment: yes, it shows it 4 times

Comment: @dobey You're right, I corrected the text accordingly. Although even Linux does not show this.

Comment: Yeah, Windows and macOS don't know really either, and at the OS level there's no useful reason to make a distinction. Behaviorally they're additional cores for the OS. The distinction only really matters when a human looks at it, and even then applications can't really know, because the OS doesn't distinguish.